# Checking checkboxes in table makes tablerow overlap thead's box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have tables with a box-shadow on the bottom of the thead. it worked perfectly untill I added checkboxes to the table. Now when I check any of the checkboxes, and then hover over the table rows. the table rows overlap the box-shadow of the thead.

The snippet was acting up so I have reconstructed the issue in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/FllnAngl/m81atv4t/1/

I gave everything below the thead a `background-color:transparent` but I can't seem to fix it and I was wondering if any of you could help me with it.

The tables look like this:

[image]

I know that what it looks like is irrelevant, but I just want to make sure you get the right idea.

I am programming in ASP.NET MVC 5 Razor so the reconstruction looks different than the image. but the issue remains. Also I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7

**Note:**  It seems like this only happens in Chrome

**EDIT**
The issue looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issue, what version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: Version 66.0.3359.170 (latest) (64bit)

Comment: try selecting multiple checkboxes. because sometimes the issue doesn't appear. but then after selecting and deselecting a couple of times, it appears

Comment: @Xoog Did it just simply work? can you elaborate?